# How to force react-native project to run on a physical android device?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to get my react-native project to run on a physical android device.
When I run "adb device", I get a proper output:

```
List of devices attached
LMX210APMc7ea5434   device
emulator-5554   device
```

However, when I run "react-native run-android", I get this:

```
react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:3285) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
/bin/sh: /Users/eugene/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

I did install the android studio, configured the SDK, added an AVD device, etc...

I also connect the device via USB, entered into developer mode, enabled USB debugging, ran adb reverse, etc...

What else do I need to to be able to run this project on a device?

Comment: Did you have your device listed in the android studio device chooser? 
Can you show screenshot of your android studio with your device connected?

Comment: Seems like it's looking for and not finding the adb `/Users/eugene/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory`. Is the path set correctly for it?

Comment: Yes, the device does how up in the android studio. In fact, I was able to run my app on the device from the android studio just now, but the react-native cli still would not work

Comment: Well, I suppose I can live with having to initiate app run on a physical device from the android studio instead of react-native cli...

Comment: Make sure that USB debugging is on inside Developers Options in your android device and you are allowing USB debugging if the device is asking for permission in a pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Usually If I need to run my project on physical device, i turn off my emulators. and it runs on device without problem. you can use npx react-native run-android --deviceId LMX210APMc7ea5434. first value of adb devices command is the deviceId.